Can I use "walletnotify" to watch outgoing transactions from a watch-only wallet?
I have a watch-only descriptor wallet. I'm interested in getting notified when funds are sent from this wallet. By looking at the code for walletnotify it seems like this is only called when funds are added to the wallet.
Is it somehow possible to configure walletnotify and a descriptor-based watch-only wallet such that I'm notified when a given UTXO is spent? Or is this otherwise possible using bitcoind?

walletnotify is called every time a wallet transaction occurs, i.e. a transaction in which at least one input or output belongs to the wallet. It doesn't matter if the transaction is incoming or outgoing, or whether it was created by the Bitcoin Core wallet or any other wallet with the same set of keys.
